# JTileDownloader gets Forbidden from Mapnik

Tags: dictionary, openstreetmap, mapnik

I need to download some tiles to use them offline in a webpage using [JTileDownloader](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JTileDownloader), version 0-6-1.

When I use Mapnik as the source, it get a 'Forbidden' message. what may be happening?

I've heard that this happens if you don't declare an user-agent, but the programs seem not to offer this option.

Anyhow, does anybody know an option to download tiles through Mapnik?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tile grabber was forbidden from downloading tiles by OSM administrators. They did not listen to any reasoning for allowing it to download tiles. The policy is that they block all tile downloaders, regardless of how it works.

If a tile layer does not matter, use another one, like MapQuest Open.

Now, to download tiles, JTileDownloader is the best option, because it is easy on a server, having delays between requests and downloading tiles in quadtile order. You will have to change `User-Agent` string, and for that you'll need to recompile the project. Download the source code:

```
svn co http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/utils/downloading/JTileDownloader/trunk/ JTileDownloader
```

Then find `TileListDownloader.java` in `src/org/...` and find a string `Agent` inside it. Replace `JTileDownloader` with any other word, and then compile and run the new version with `ant run` in JTD's root directory.

Note that you should not download too many tiles, that is, more than a couple thousand. If you need more, please install PostgreSQL and Mapnik and generate as many tiles as you like locally.

Comment: You do not need to recompile source. Just run jTileDownloader-0-6-1.jar and fill in some alternative tile server: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers (e.g. I used https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/ and downloading works fine)

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of differend tile grabbers [got blocked](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Blocked) as they didn't respected OSMs [Tile usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_Usage_Policy) and stressed the servers.

You are free to upgrade or pick other [similar applications](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Category%3aTile_downloading), choose a different [3rd party OSM map provider](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles), or setup your own renderer for offline rendering.

Comment: but they say here http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JTileDownloader that JTileDownloader 0-6-1 is allowed to download. why is it not working than?